# Comparing date strings using joda time library

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two date strings say , "2011-04-29" and "2011-01-28" , and i want to compare them using Joda Time. Is there a way to do that ?. An example would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "compare them"?

Comment: I mean determining which comes first

Comment: Dates in that format are already comparable as Strings, you don't need Jodatime.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to parse them. Use [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime dateTime1 = fmt.parseDateTime(string1);
```

Then use `DateTime.isBefore(..)` to compare them:

```
if (dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Can also be used ltn4java the library as follows:

```
    DataCompare dc = new DataCompare();
    int Resultado;
    Resultado = dc.compareWithTwoDatesString("2011-04-29","2011-01-28","yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The download page of the Library is http://code.google.com/p/ltn4java/downloads/list

Answer (score 2):

If your date strings are in format "yyyy-MM-dd" you can apply simple string comparison:

```
String s1 = new String("2012-01-27");
String s2 = new String("2011-01-28");
System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));
```

The result will be TRUE if s1 is lexicographically "bigger" than s2 and that's what you need. To get more info read javadoc for compareTo() method.

Comment: why would you want to create a new string?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the strings to date objects and compare those.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Bozho's answer we can use 
[AbstractInterval.isAfter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html)
:

```
if (dateTime2.isAfter(dateTime1))
```